# insert pdf with form into another pdf

Tags: forms, pdf, itext, itext7

I have a pdf with form and want to insert it into another pdf, its form has been filled, but inserted pdf's form shows no value.

Codes as follow:

```
using (PdfDocument pdfOutputDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFilePath), 
new PdfWriter(destFilePath)),
formPdfCodument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(formFilePath)))
{
    PdfFormXObject pdfDocXObject = formPdfCodument .GetFirstPage().CopyAsFormXObject(pdfOutputDoc);
    PdfStampAnnotation annotation = new PdfStampAnnotation(new Rectangle(10,10));
    annotation.SetStampName(new PdfName("itext7"));
    annotation.SetNormalAppearance(pdfDocXObject.GetPdfObject());
    pdfOutputDoc.GetFirstPage().AddAnnotation(stamp);

}
```

The file at "destFilePath" does not contain file's form value, the place of form value is blank, is there anyway shows it?

Comment: Not clear what you trying to do. Sounds like you need to use the `PdfMerger` instead?

Comment: @Lonzak I tried to embed a stamp in a pdf. I make pdf stamp with form, fill the form then embed it into another pdf.

Comment: @KJ thx for your advise, I do find it much trouble, what's your suggestion if I want to embed a dynamic stamp?

Comment: Please be aware that a PDF *form Xobject* in spite of its name can only contain static content, in particular no form widgets. By using `CopyAsFormXObject`, therefore,  you lose all your dynamic form fields from `formPdfCodument .GetFirstPage()`. If you only want the field contents to show in the result, flatten the form first.

Answer (score 1):

As directed by @mkl comment, flattened form can be embed. Just like @K J comment, a bit complex, but it works.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();//memory or buffer to be used for flattened form output.
PdfDocument formPdfDodument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(formFilePath),new PdfWriter(ms));
PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(tempPdfDodument, false).FlattenFields();
formPdfDodument.Close();
PdfDocument tempPdfDodument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(ms.GetBuffer())));
PdfDocument pdfOutputDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFilePath), new PdfWriter(destFilePath));
PdfFormXObject pdfDocXObject = tempPdfDodument.GetFirstPage().CopyAsFormXObject(pdfOutputDoc);
PdfStampAnnotation annotation = new PdfStampAnnotation(new Rectangle(10,10));
annotation.SetStampName(new PdfName("itext7"));
annotation.SetNormalAppearance(pdfDocXObject.GetPdfObject());
pdfOutputDoc.GetFirstPage().AddAnnotation(stamp);
```